# Media Lovin Toolkit in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, mlt

I want to create an application in Node.JS that uses MLT(Media Lovin Toolkit) for mixing some videos and streaming through RTMP.

I found one package that generates XML instructions for MLT, but it does not include Consumer's functionality, so I cannot stream using it. (https://github.com/redmantech/node-mlt)

Moreover, I tried building the MLT source code as there seems to be a a way to use MLT through JavaScript using SWIG that compiles the JavaScript code to C Language, but there seem to be other problems on building the code. (https://github.com/mltframework/mlt)

Is there any way of doing this?